# Use sub-query with update statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle

I have to update the top 2 rows of a column based on the select top 2 statement with some expressions.

```
update top(2) [Travel].[dbo].[HOTELS]
set [Travel].[dbo].[HOTELS].NAME = (select top(2) SUBSTRING(Name, 1, 5) + 'xxxxx' + SUBSTRING(Name, LEN(Name) - 2, LEN(Name)) AS column1
                                    from [Travel].[dbo].[HOTELS]                                    
                                   )
```

With the above query I'm getting this error

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

I have to use this in both SQL Server and in Oracle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your subquery you have top 2 change the limit to 1

```
update top 2  [Travel].[dbo].[HOTELS]
   set [Travel].[dbo].[HOTELS].NAME  = (
     select top 1  SUBSTRING(Name, 1, 5) + 'xxxxx' + SUBSTRING(Name, LEN(Name) - 2, LEN(Name)) AS column1
    from [Travel].[dbo].[HOTELS]
    where [Travel].[dbo].[HOTELS].id = 1415
  )
```

And if you don't want the where condition  then don't use it eg:

```
  update top 2  [Travel].[dbo].[HOTELS]
set [Travel].[dbo].[HOTELS].NAME  = (
    select top 1  SUBSTRING(Name, 1, 5) + 'xxxxx' + SUBSTRING(Name, LEN(Name) - 2, LEN(Name)) AS column1
    from [Travel].[dbo].[HOTELS]

  )
```

Comment: i dont want to use the "where [Travel].[dbo].[HOTELS].id = 1415".

Comment: answer  updated   .. for first sample..   just don't use the where condition

Comment: update top (2)  [Travel].[dbo].[HOTELS]
set [Travel].[dbo].[HOTELS].NAME in (
    select top (2)  SUBSTRING(Name, 1, 5) + 'xxxxx' + SUBSTRING(Name, LEN(Name) - 2, LEN(Name)) AS column1
    from [Travel].[dbo].[HOTELS]

  )  when i use this am getting an error Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 54
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'in'.

Comment: @Raj answer  updated ..  si not allowed  assigne more value in at field with set  ..  so you can just use proper limit

Comment: @scaisaEdge --> you mean IN statement will not work ??

Comment: IN clause can't work in a SET assignement ...  is not possible assigne more than a value  to a field in UPDATE..  is a basic logic .. anyway  so your subquery must return just one value and use = for assign.. .. looking to your comment to others  answer ..  you can't use the same code  for ORACLE and SQL-SERVER with  limit  .. because the sintax for the tow db is diffirent

Comment: in that case what is the solution for updating top X values of a column based on the sub-query which will return the same X values ?

Answer (score 0):

in sql-server you can use `cte + select data first` then update it.

> ```
> CREATE TABLE HOTELS
>   ([NAME] varchar(14))
> ;
>
> INSERT INTO HOTELS
>   ([NAME])
> VALUES
>   ('ABCDEFG'),
>   ('HIJKLMOP')
> ;
> GO
> ```

> ```
> with cte as (
>     select top 2 NAME, SUBSTRING(Name, 1, 5) + 'xxxxx' + SUBSTRING(Name, LEN(Name) - 2, LEN(Name)) AS column1
>     from [HOTELS]
> )
> update cte set NAME = column1;
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> 2 rows affected
> ```

> ```
> select * from HOTELS;
> ```
>
> ```
> | NAME          |
> | :------------ |
> | ABCDExxxxxEFG |
> | HIJKLxxxxxMOP |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2012&fiddle=3462e2030ed84eed5c72d542a76fc9f4)*

---

edit for oracle version

> ```
> CREATE TABLE Table1
>   ("NAME" varchar2(80))
> ;
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> INSERT ALL 
>   INTO Table1 ("NAME")
>        VALUES ('ABCDEFG')
>   INTO Table1 ("NAME")
>        VALUES ('HIJKLMOP')
> SELECT * FROM dual
> ;
> ```
>
> ```
> 2 rows affected
> ```

> ```
> update Table1
> set name = SUBSTR(Name, 1, 5) || 'xxxxx' || SUBSTR(Name, LENGTH(Name) - 2, LENGTH(Name)-1)
> where rownum <= 2
> ```
>
> ```
> 2 rows affected
> ```

> ```
> select * from Table1
> ```
>
> ```
> | NAME          |
> | :------------ |
> | ABCDExxxxxEFG |
> | HIJKLxxxxxMOP |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=45634d0f6534017cbce60ac861d3bb80)*

Comment: [online demo link](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2012&fiddle=3462e2030ed84eed5c72d542a76fc9f4)

Comment: how do i solve this in oracle server ? dose oracle also has cte ???